# Shader including another shader?

Tags: xna, shader

Is it possible, using XNA 4, to include a Shader within another shader?  I know you could do this within 3.1, but I seem to be having trouble getting this to work?  If you can, any pointers would be great.

**EDIT**

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// Name : Rain.fx
// Desc : Rain particle effect using cylindrical billboards
// Author   : Justin Stoecker. Copyright (C) 2008-2009.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//

#include "common.inc"  // It's this line that causes me a problem

float4x4 matWorld;

float3 vVelocity;
float3 vOrigin;         // min point of the cube area
float fWidth;           // width of the weather region (x-axis)
float fHeight;          // height of the weather region (y-axis)
float fLength;          // length of the weather region (z-axis)

... Rest of file ...
```

The "common.inc" file has variables in there, but I was wondering if you could put methods in there as well?

Comment: Can you give an XNA 3.1 example?

Comment: @Andrew Russell: Updated question

Comment: You say it causes you a "problem" - can you be more specific? Error message? Also it's worth pointing out: the content pipeline was updated to use a newer version of the shader compiler in XNA 4.0.

Comment: I'm not at the computer now, but will get the error message. In the meantime, is it possible to use includes in a shader with methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible, from memory I think the basic effect example shader example from the MS App Hub does it.

In any case, see code below!

In `FractalBase.fxh`

```
float4x4 MatrixTransform : register(vs, c0);

float2 Pan;
float Zoom;
float Aspect;

float ZPower = 2;

float3 Colour = 0;
float3 ColourScale = 0;

float ComAbs(float2 Arg)
{

}

float2 ComSquare(float2 Arg)
{

}

int GreaterThan(float x, float y)
{

}

float4 GetColour(int DoneIterations, float MaxIterations, float BailoutTest, float OldBailoutTest, float BailoutFigure)
{

}

void SpriteVertexShader(inout float4 Colour    : COLOR0,
                        inout float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0,
                        inout float4 position : SV_Position)
{
    position = mul(position, MatrixTransform);

    // Convert the position into from screen space into complex coordinates
    texCoord = (position) * Zoom * float2(1, Aspect) - float2(Pan.x, -Pan.y);
}
```

In `FractalMandelbrot.fx`

```
#include "FractalBase.fxh"

float4 FractalPixelShader(float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0, uniform float Iterations) : COLOR0
{

}

technique Technique1
{
    pass
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 SpriteVertexShader();
        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 FractalPixelShader(128);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is an `fxh` file like a C++ `header` file?

Comment: @Neil, yes it's like a C++ header file.

Answer (score 2):

`#include`s work like this:

The preprocessor loads your main .fx file, and parses it, looking for anything that starts with a `#`. `#include`s cause the preprocessor to load the referenced file and insert its contents into the source buffer. Effectively, your `#include` directive is replaced by the entire contents of the included file.

So, yes, you can define anything in your `#include`s that you can define in a regular .fx file. I use this for keeping lighting functions, vertex type declarations, etc in common files that are used by several shaders.